# FFMpeg Draw Text Like Animation

Tags: windows, command-line, ffmpeg

I am trying to draw text on my video using ffmpeg.

Text is:
"Please Wait, System Is Loading..."

here is the code i used:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -vf drawtext="fontfile=1.ttf: \text='Please Wait, System Is Loading...': fontcolor=0x0080FF: fontsize=48: box=1: boxcolor=white@0.1: \boxborderw=5: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-(text_h+25))" -codec:a copy "output.mp4"
```

that worked good, but what i like is to make the text look like animated:
So, every 0.5 second it should change to following lines and loop it:

Please Wait, System Is Loading.

Please Wait, System Is Loading..

Please Wait, System Is Loading...

Please Wait, System Is Loading...!

i know it's possible i just can figure out it how :(

thanks in advance
best regards

Comment: somebody? anybody? any help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late but the solution is `enable='between(t, {start}, {end})'` available on drawtext filter:

You will have to draw each text by separate filter, so you will create 4 texts and add them on a transparent background:

`-t 2 -i color=black@0:{size}, format=rgba -i your_video.mp4`

`-filter_complex "[0] drawtext=...:enable='between(t, 0, 0.5)', drawtext=...:enable='between(t, 0.501, 1)', ... [texts]"`

The duration of color background set to 2 seconds for 4 texts, each 0.5 seconds.

Then you overlay them looping over the video:

```
[1] [texts] overlay={x}:{y}:eof_action=repeat [out]
```

Then map your output streams:

```
-map [out] -map 1:a {codecs}
```

This way the video taken out from the filter and the audio taken from the video.